# Find optimized input value of a custom function for specific target value

Tags: r, optimization

Assuming we have a custom function like:

```
f <- function(i){
  return(i*i)
}
```

and we have a target value like 25. I want to find the "ideal" input `i` for this function in a certain range. This is pretty simple, but i don't want to solve this issue by solving the equation, since my original function is much more complicated (which still can be solved, but that's not the point).

Which function / algorithm can I use to optimize the input value `i`, so we get the closest to the target value. I using brute force by just creating a mass of inputs like:

```
for (i in -1000:1000){
    test_values <- c(test_values, f(i))
}
```

and then finding the minimum of this by using:

```
which.min(abs(test_values-p_target))
```

But i can't imagine there is not an algorithm for this, but I also can't find anything for this. Obviously my method is very inefficient. Optimization functions like `optimize` or `uniroot` are all looking for min or max and not target values. So anyone knows an algorithm or function for optimizing this problem in general?

Comment: Why is `optimize` not the best general solution here?

Comment: @r2evans maybe i just don't understand it correctly, but you are just getting the optimized min of the function and the min of the target_value? When i use `optimize(f, c(-5,5))` i get the return value `0', which is of course right. I don't see how i can give optimize a target value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reformulate your objective function `f` as below (since you should minimize the distance between i**2 and 25), and then use `optimize()` to solve it

```
objfun <- function(x, target=25) norm(f(x)-target,"2")
res <- optimize(objfun,interval = c(-100,100),tol = 1e-10)
```

such that

```
> res
$minimum
[1] 5

$objective
[1] 1.635312e-07
```

then you will see the `res$minimum` gives 5 for your desired output.